# Why do I set up code splitting in the react project, but no asynchronous chunks file is generated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

As I said, I use webpack4.0, using the official lazy loading method to code partitioning in my own reactive project, to achieve lazy loading, but after I packaged, I have been unable to export the resulting chunks file. What happened? Please help me, here is my configuration code.

```js
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCssAssetsWebpackPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const Autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const {
  BundleAnalyzerPlugin
} = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');

module.exports = env => {

  const rules = [
    {
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/
    },
    {
      test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|svg)$/,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 100000
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: [
        env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
          ? 'style-loader'
          : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        'css-loader'
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.less$/,
      use: [
        env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
          ? 'style-loader'
          : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        'css-loader',
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            ident: 'postcss',
            plugins: [Autoprefixer()]
          }
        },
        'less-loader'
      ]
    }
  ];

  const plugins = {
    development: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: 'index.html',
        injetc: 'body'
      }),
      new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
      new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()
    ],
    production: [
      new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].min.css'
      }),
      new OptimizeCssAssetsWebpackPlugin(), 
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: 'index.html',
        injetc: 'body'
      }),
      new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()
    ],
    test: [new BundleAnalyzerPlugin()]
  };

  const webpackConfig = {
    entry: {
      index: './src/index.js'
    },
    devtool: 'nosources-source-map',
    output: {
      filename: '[name].[hash].js',
      chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    module: {
      rules: [...rules]
    },

    optimization: {
      runtimeChunk: {
        name: 'manifest'
      },
      splitChunks: {
        maxAsyncRequests: 10,
        cacheGroups: {
          default: false,
          async: {
            name: 'async',
            chunks: 'async',
            minChunks: 1,
            minSize: 1,
            priority: 20
          },
          common: {
            name: 'common',
            chunks: 'initial',
            minChunks: 1,
            minSize: 1,
            priority: 0
          },
          vander: {
            name: 'base',
            test: /node_modules/,
            chunks: 'initial',
            minChunks: 1,
            priority: 10
          }
        }
      }
    },


    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(env.NODE_ENV)
      }),
      ...plugins[env.NODE_ENV]
    ]
  };


  if (env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    webpackConfig.devServer = {
      hot: true,
      hotOnly: true
    };
  }
  console.log(webpackConfig);
  return webpackConfig;
};
```

#### React configuration code

```js
import loadable from '@loadable/component';

 <Content>
            <Route
              path="/home/discover"
              component={loadable(() =>
                import('../Discover')
              )}
            />
            <Route
              path="/home/visilize"
              component={loadable(() =>
                import('../Visilize')
              )}
            />
            <Route
              path="/home/dashboard"
              component={loadable(() =>
                import('../Dashboard')
              )}
            />
            <Route
              path="/home/data"
              component={loadable(() => import('../Data'))}
            />
            <Route
              path="/home/alarm"
              component={loadable(() => import('../Alarm'))}
            />
          </Content>
```

The result of his production is as follows

[image]

Comment: Look at the packaging result of this picture, why the index.js file is packaged out is index.bundle.js, he is the entry file, should the chunksname not work for him.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing lazy-loading is super smooth in React 16.6. I haven't tried my hands on loadable but use `React.lazy()` for the same. Its easy to understand and write. Here is sample syntax:

```
const OtherComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./OtherComponent'));

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <OtherComponent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Check this for details:

https://scotch.io/bar-talk/whats-new-in-react-166#toc-react-lazy-and-suspense

Comment: hank you for your answer, it has already come out, thank you very much.

Comment: @json.iv could you please accept this as answer if it helped.